# Is there any way to make a drawer with three-states?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, materialdrawer

I would like to make a drawer with three different states. The drawer opened state, a closed state and a third semi-open mini drawer state like:
[image]

I have been able to implement mini drawer and open using the material drawer library but have been unable to close it.

Any suggestions on how to do this? (Either Kotlin or Java is fine)

Comment: As already mentioned on your GitHub issue too: https://github.com/mikepenz/Crossfader/issues/13#issuecomment-328395601

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I just didn't want to go through the hassle and was wondering if there was some easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project does not support this. A custom layout must be implemented.